# ACF relationship field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an odd issue, which i’m not sure is possible.

I have set up a user relationship field which allows you to add users to your list (in a pseudo way as a “friend” or “connection”. The client would like a way to show a list of people who have added you to their account.

I thought that this may be possible with another acf relationship field. But I can’t for the life of me work out how to achieve this.

Any ideas?